# Differences between Cortex-M4 Cortex-M7 and Cortex-A5

Tags: cortex

I want to make a simple IOT project for my home and I'm searching for a mcu to start with. I was raffling through the web site of a few popular distributors and I found that some Cortex-M4 are much more expensive than Cortex-M7 which are more powerful though. Also I saw that some Cortex-A5 are cheaper than some Cortex-M7.

I can understand the differences in terms of performance and architecture, but if someone wants to start developing a board based on some of the MCUs that mentioned above for building its own projects, what statements must be considered to match our demands?

To be exact, why not choosing a Cortex-A5 if it's more cheaper and powerful instead of a Cortex-M7?

Comment: It really depends on the application. What you need it to do, how energy efficient does it need to be, how powerful, etc? And then you have to weigh in other factors like size and layout. If it's a simple IoT project then probably the M series. https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/Which-ARM-Cortex-Core-Is-Right-for-Your-Application.pdf

Comment: 1) If you're doing an IoT project, you have to figure out what you are using for connectivity first, both hardware and software.  2) Keep in mind that while Cortex-M parts typically have on-board Flash and RAM, Cortex-A parts will need those provided externally, which adds cost and circuit complexity (though they can be orders of magnitude higher in capacity).  Flash sizes are a large driver in MCU incremental costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stress *some* are cheaper. Cortexes are just microprocessor IP cores that semiconductor companies buy from ARM. The CPU core is one of many cost factors in a microcontroller.

Comparing A5 to M something isn't fair. They were designed for totally different customer classes, and the fact that some A5s are cheap is an effect of

- economics of scale and
- the fact that you pay for the silicon quality, and hence, reliability you get

The exact core architecture of the microcontroller you're planning to use is, I daresay, a secondary feature, especially with arms, since there's simply mature C compilers, so you normally select by the peripherals you need and the compute performance and things like *overall* power efficiency.

What's the benefit of having a very watt per megaflop-effective core when you're in deep sleep mode 99.95% of time, and the smaller microcontroller would allow you to shut down the external oscillator but the efficient bigger one won't?

What's the disadvantage if your processor core actually uses ten times more energy, but your system's power consumption is defined by the heavily loaded output of a PWM unit?

What good is a high-performance MCU when it needs much better quality power supply?

What about not having something with a large BGA pinout that makes two-layer boards impossible?

Why throughput when what you need is guaranteed interrupt latency, instead?

Comment: And what about the competition amidst M7 and M4? As I mentioned in my first post, some M4 are more expensive than M7, that may be due to the internal peripheral's scale, but what considerations ought to be carried out between Cortexes?